# Implicit using statements in ASP.NET CORE 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a solution called DoeWeb that has a Models folder.
When I add a View I have to explicitly refer to the models folder in the view like this:

```
    @using DoeWeb.Models;
@model IEnumerable<Division>
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h1>Divisions</h1>
```

If I do not explicitly state that, it says :

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'Division' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I know in ASP.NET CORE 6 you do not need this explicit using statement. How do you configure that?

Comment: Are you talking about [global usings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-10#global-using-directives)?

Comment: Anything that works! I do not know the exact names.

Answer (score 0):

For ASP.NET Core MVC you can use [`_ViewImports.cshtml` file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/layout?view=aspnetcore-7.0#importing-shared-directives). Usually it is located in the root of the `Views` folder. Just add there :

```cs
@using DoeWeb.Models;
```